# Javascript 2 dimensional arrays for text replacement in html

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

hey got some "simple" text-replace problem ... got an html-page and want to do some easy replacing with a 2 dimensional field

the function "createArray" is out of an answer on a similar question but i cant get this working :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function createArray(length) {
    var arr = new Array(length || 0),
        i = length;

    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        while(i--) arr[length-1 - i] = createArray.apply(this, args);
    }

    return arr;
}

window.onload = function(){
    var tabelle = createArray(14, 2);
        tabelle[0][0]="Comment:Header";     tabelle[0][1]="test";
        tabelle[1][0]="Comment:Lane";       tabelle[1][1]=" ";
        tabelle[2][0]="Comment:VS";         tabelle[2][1]=" ";
        tabelle[3][0]="Comment:Early1";     tabelle[3][1]=" ";
        tabelle[4][0]="Comment:Early2";     tabelle[4][1]=" ";
        tabelle[5][0]="Comment:Early3";     tabelle[5][1]=" ";
        tabelle[6][0]="Comment:Mid1";       tabelle[6][1]=" ";
        tabelle[7][0]="Comment:Mid2";       tabelle[7][1]=" ";
        tabelle[8][0]="Comment:Mid3";       tabelle[8][1]=" ";
        tabelle[9][0]="Comment:Late1";      tabelle[9][1]=" ";
        tabelle[10][0]="Comment:Late2";     tabelle[10][1]=" ";
        tabelle[11][0]="Comment:Late3";     tabelle[11][1]=" ";
        tabelle[12][0]="Comment:etc1";      tabelle[12][1]=" ";
        tabelle[13][0]="Comment:etc2";      tabelle[13][1]=" ";
    for (var i = 0; i < tabelle.length; i++)
        document.body.innerHTML = 
        document.body.innerHTML.replace(tabelle[i][0], tabelle[i][1]);
    };
</script>
```

thx already ;D

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/kF7kg/

Comment: You really should use an array literal…

Comment: its just for the purpose of lazyness, because i can fill my table with just mashin the down button on my keyboard

Comment: An array literal would simplify even that…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this in a different way.

```
var replacements = {
        "Comment:Header": "test",
        "Comment:whatever": "test2",
        // etc..
};
window.onload = function(event) {
    for (var key in replacements) {
        if (replacements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {  
            document.body.innerHTML =
               document.body.innerHTML.replace(key, replacements[key]);
        };
    };
};
```

I would really avoid the entire hassle. There is a far simpler and more suitable approach to what you are trying to do. And it is also the default way to deal with such things.

- Less code.
- Far more readable.
- Easy to maintain.
- Easy to check if a replacement exists(`typeof replacements["Comment:whatever"] !== 'undefined'`). O(1), no conversions necessary. No searching algorithm required.
- No JS weirdness and pointless operations.
- Execution is faster, performance gain negligible but exists.
- Can be internationalized.

And [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/LuZxV/6/) is the working Fiddle.

Comment: this is lookin really good ... but i cant find a reason why its not workin on the target site :(

Comment: the script is workin and normal alerts get called but its not replacing the strings =(

Comment: fiddle is workin .. but the site the script should work on isnt

Comment: none that is my problem ... no error and its just doin nothin ... and when i put some code like alert("testing stuff") in the end of the function it is gettin executed i get the alert :(

Answer (score 2):

More info about your error would help, but I did notice that you had:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 14; i++)
```

instead of the correct:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++)
```

or even better:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tabelle.length; i++)
```

Comment: …or even better `i < tabelle.length`

Comment: well im gettin just nothin gotta look into the js console but simply this script does nothin:(

Comment: @KeKsCoRe, can you edit your OP to paste in your html as well, or better yet create a http://jsfiddle.net with your html and js together?

Comment: So it works in jsfiddle, but the same code is not working on your site?  What differences are there?  Is the actual data different?

Comment: well the whole thing is wrapped in millions of divs and spans but nope not really

Comment: At least now you have isolated the problem, and you know there is nothing wrong with the code in your OP, given the changes we made.  So the problem must lie somewhere else.  It's impossible to help anymore though without seeing the exact page you are seeing.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320486/how-safe-is-it-use-document-body-innerhtml-replace.  I think your next step is to target the text of the specific DOM nodes that you want to replace, rather than doing the blanket body.innerHTML replace.

Comment: i think i kinda made my issue way more complicated then it is :(

so here a try to get it as easy as possible:
    1. i got some html that i want to replace (could do this 1 for 1 in the html)
but 
    2. i wanted it all in the top so i have all my input in some fields and dont have to rewrite my html code (wich is part of a side im not owning (just misusing their side for my own purposes))

    3. there are like 10 gamereports on 1 page ... and the js will replace every comment tag with the js that gets executed last ... not my intention :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code works great for me. The problem you having is properbly because you forget to run the srcript after page is loaded. So you might be calling `document.body.innerHTML` when `document.body` is not there yet.

Remeber to wrap them in

```
window.onload = function() {
   //doing something here
};
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9aP86/1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: `Unhandled Error: Cannot convert 'tabelle[i]' to object` when `i` == 14?