# Want to perform php using OnClick function without clearing the current web page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the js script at the bottom of my wp post.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var id = 'downloadid';

var data_from_ajax;

$.post('download.php', {id : id}) .done(function(data) {
  data_from_ajax = data;
});

function hey() {
document.write(data_from_ajax);
}

</script>
```

Function hey was being called from a link OnClick function. When using this, the page would successfully perform the php code on download php (update a db then download a file) although it would clear the current page I was on. What I wanted to do was perform the php and keep the current page template. So next I tried using

```
document.getElementById("download").innerHTML = data_from_ajax;
```

instead of document.write. I made a div with the id download. Now when I click it, it simply won't perform the php. when I replace the data_from_ajax with a string, it gladly puts it in the div though.

Any help would be great.

EDIT:
my html is

```
<a href="#" onClick="hey()">download</a>

<div id='download'>&nbsp</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7smJE/

Comment: @AMR explain how he will get hacked please.

Comment: He also already is using Ajax

Comment: More html code would help. or a fiddle.Just making sure, You made a div called download, you mean you made div like this? `<div id='download'></div>`

Comment: @crush read http://www.amazon.com/Deadly-Sins-Software-Security-Programming/dp/0071626751

Comment: You want me to buy a book? Did you write it? How about you just tell us how he would get hacked in that scenario, considering the contents are coming from HIS site.

Comment: @crush okay here is an SO answer maybe you can read that instead. Im not here to provide a lecture for you. Do some research if your interested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320486/how-safe-is-it-use-document-body-innerhtml-replace

Comment: Yes with the id download <div id='download'>&nbsp;</div>

Comment: @AMR that has nothing to do with being hacked.

Comment: @crush k nm you obviously are smarter than me

Comment: @AMR No, I just don't go around saying ignorant things like "you will get hacked if you use .innerHTML".

Comment: @crush having knowledge of cross site scripting is hardly ignorant. I dont understand why you would want to troll this but w/e more power to you. Im done.

Comment: @AMR You are applying a blanket statement. It isn't simply 100% always hackable. You clearly don't understand how cross-site scripting works if you believe that.

Comment: Please continue. The popcorn is almost ready.

Comment: It's simple. `.innerHTML` accepts an input. If you sanitize that input, then you are not in danger of being hacked. If you fail at sanitization, and are inputting data that could come from a third party, then you are in danger of being hacked. Thus, it's not 100% guaranteed to be hackable. Nice try.

Comment: So uhh.. anyways.. about the scripting...
http://jsfiddle.net/7smJE/ idk if that says anything more than my post but here a fiddle is.

Comment: You sure you have a `div` with `download` id? Please put your HTML and your click code.

Comment: When I try to change the inner html to a string it will output the string, it just won't perform the php.

Comment: @user2087587 Your `$.post` call to your PHP file is getting executed at page load, and not when you click the link. I think you need to `e.preventDefault()` in your `onclick` handler, or set the href attribute to `javascript:void(0)` to prevent the page from being reloaded when you click the link.

Comment: @crush I think he wants to do that and keep returned data so he can show it later.

Comment: using javascript:void(0) still clears the page

Comment: @user2087587 BTW, if you're using jQuery so use this instead: `$("#download").html(data_from_ajax)`

Comment: @MahanGM
`$("#download").html(data_from_ajax)` clears the page as well, but when I use
`$("#download").html('string')` it just adds the word string to the div. Confused on why this is happening differently.

Comment: Does `data_from_ajax` contain `<html>...</html>` by any chance?

Comment: @JakubMichálek No but it redirects to a download, has <script>...</script>, and <php>...<?php> if that helps.

Comment: @user2087587 How come it clears the page if you're just changing one div? I'm really clueless on your issue here and fiddle doesn't help since `download.php` is not working there. Can you put the result of `data_from_ajax` as well?

Comment: @MahanGM That's what's making me clueless. It's long and messy but here is download.php http://pastebin.com/VkVWcTiC . If I put that php right in the div I'm trying to change, it will work, but I need it to work only when I click the link.

Comment: even
$("#download").replaceWith(data_from_ajax) will clear the whole page. I don't know why so it must be something in my php code.

Comment: You're writing on document from your PHP file and you expect it to be just in `download` div? remove any `document.write()` from your print functions in PHP file and instead print the content directly then it'll return it as a displayable string data which you can present it in `download`.

Comment: This makes sense now. I feel stupid. Any way to use the unescape javascript function without using document.write()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP code which you've provided, I think you should replace `document.write()` in your code with `$('#download').html()`. This way you don't need to put the returned result in your `download` div anymore because when PHP page gets loaded it'll do this for you and you have to put your `$.post` in `hey()` function too because you need this to perform when your link gets clicked.

PHP:

```
<?php
$fileid = $id;
if (is_file('d84ue9d/' . $fileid . '.apk'))
{
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","docvet95_check","%tothemax%","docvet95_downcheck");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `download-check` where ip = '$ip'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$files = $row['files'];
$downloads = $row['downloads'];
}
if ($downloads > 4)
{
print "$('#download').html(unescape('%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%22%3E%0A%61%6C%65%72%74%28%27%59%6F%75%5C%27%76%65%20%64%6F%77%6E%6C%6F%61%64%65%64%20%66%69%76%65%20%6F%72%20%6D%6F%72%65%20%66%69%6C%65%73%2E%20%46%6F%72%20%72%69%67%68%74%20%6E%6F%77%2C%20%74%68%69%73%20%69%73%20%6F%6B%61%79%2E%20%49%6E%20%74%68%65%20%66%75%74%75%72%65%2C%20%79%6F%75%20%77%69%6C%6C%20%6E%65%65%64%20%74%6F%20%63%6F%6D%70%6C%65%74%65%20%61%20%73%75%72%76%65%79%20%69%6E%20%6F%72%64%65%72%20%74%6F%20%63%6F%6E%74%69%6E%75%65%20%64%6F%77%6E%6C%6F%61%64%69%6E%67%2E%20%54%68%61%6E%6B%20%79%6F%75%20%66%6F%72%20%75%73%69%6E%67%20%6F%75%72%20%77%65%62%73%69%74%65%27%29%3B%20%0A%77%69%6E%64%6F%77%2E%6F%70%65%6E%28%27%2F%61%70%6B%73%2F%64%38%34%75%65%39%64%2F". $fileid . "%2E%61%70%6B%27%2C%27%5F%73%65%6C%66%27%29%0A%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E'));";

}
else
{
$downloadq = $downloads + 1;
$there = $result->num_rows;
if ($there <1)
{
$addidnip = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `download-check` (ip, files, downloads) VALUES ('$ip', '$fileid', 1)");
}
else
{
$idtoarray = explode(",", $files);
if (!in_array($fileid, $idtoarray))
{
array_push($idtoarray, $fileid);
$newfile = implode(",", $idtoarray);
$adddw = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `download-check` SET downloads=$downloadq, files='$newfile' where ip = '$ip'");

}
}
print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";

print "$('#download').html(unescape('%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%74%79%70%65%3D%22%74%65%78%74%2F%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%22%3E%0A%77%69%6E%64%6F%77%2E%6F%70%65%6E%28%27%64%38%34%75%65%39%64%2F". $fileid . "%2E%61%70%6B%27%2C%27%5F%73%65%6C%66%27%29%0A%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E'));";
print "</script>";
}
}
else
{ echo 'Whoops, looks like we couldn\'t find that file. You could try searching for it?'; }

?>
```

JavaScript:

```
var id = 'downloadid';

var data_from_ajax;

function hey() {
  $.post('download.php', {id : id});
}
```

But I recommend you to return the exact data from your PHP without any extra tag and then use it this way:

```
var id = 'downloadid';

function hey() {
  $.post('download.php', {id : id}).done(function(data) {
    $("#download").html(unescape(data));
  });
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect. I will test it after food. Accepting as right now.

Comment: I worship the ground you walk on.

Comment: @user2087587 I'm glad that you made it :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see without the fiddle:

The `hey` function is probably fired before the `done` function is ready. Why don't you call `hey()` from within `done()`?

Comment: The `$.post` is happening on page load, not when the button is clicked. Unless he has a really slow connection between client and where the PHP file is hosted, it is unlikely, though, very possible, that `done` is not finishing before `hey()` is executing.

Comment: I think what he is missing is suppressing the default action of the hyperlink he is clicking to execute the hey function.

Comment: Ok, but the link action will only move him to the hash code, not necessarily reload the page. And of course, it is still unclear when and where `hey()` is actually fired.

Comment: @crush hyperlink would still response to `onclick`.

Comment: @cars10 If he clicks the link before the data is returned from AJAX, it is entirely possible that you're right.

Comment: He should either perform the `$.post` when the link is clicked, and then put the response in the innerHTML on the `done` function, or, disable the link until the `$.post` completes.

Comment: Isn`t the common way to place the success function something like `$.post(URL,data, function(){/* do the action...*/})`? Does the `.done()` construct really work in this case?

Comment: I believe that the `.done()` function does work in this case because it is what sets the `data_from_ajax` which is successfully called when I use `window.write(data_from_ajax)`

Comment: How large is the text/HTML that you are trying to insert? Is it possible that it is not compatible to be placed inside a div? Can you post the contents that you try to insert?

Comment: The contents are a lot of messy if php statements and some encrypted code and messy comments that is really hard to follow.